# How to Send the Correct Request to API Using Dio/Flutter (Frontend) & Go (Backend)

Tags: android, flutter, go, go-gin, dio

I'm testing this in Android Studio right now. This is my Go code that I'm trying to use in my Flutter frontend:

```
func Login(c *gin.Context) {
    //  Get email and password off of req body
    var body struct {
        Email    string
        Password string
    }

    if c.Bind(&body) != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Failed to read body",
        })

        return
    }

    var user models.User
    if user.ID == 0 {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Invalid email and/or password",
        })
        return
    }

    // Lookup user by email, including records where deleted_at is NULL
    if err := initializers.DB.Where("email = ? AND deleted_at IS NULL", body.Email).First(&user).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Invalid email and/or password",
        })
        return
    }

    //  Compare passwords
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(body.Password))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Invalid email and/or password",
        })
        return
    }

    //  Generate JWT Token
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "sub": user.ID,
        "exp": time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 30).Unix(),
    })
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")))

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Failed to create token",
        })
        return
    }

    //  Send back
    c.SetSameSite(http.SameSiteLaxMode)
    c.SetCookie("AuthZ", tokenString, 3600*24*30, "", "", false, true)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{})
}

//main,go

    r.POST("/login", controllers.Login)
```

I keep getting a 400 error code and I'm trying to parse out why. Here's how I'm sending the request:

```
void postLogin(String email, String password) async {
  Response response;
  response = await _dio.post('$baseUrl/login', data: {
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
  });
}

...

try {
                          postLogin(
                              emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                          print('Login successful');
                        } catch (error) {
                          print('Login failed: $error');
                          // Print Dio error message
                          if (error is DioError) {
                            print('Dio error message: ${error.message}');
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            errorText =
                                'Login failed. Please check your credentials.';
                          });
                        } finally {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = false;
                          });
                        }
```

The API works in Postman and through other testing methods, but it doesn't work in Android Studio, at least not with the way I'm using Dio.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does it even jump in your request handler in Go? Put a breakpoint to verify this, but 400 should be a client side error. You may need to add application/json as a Content-Type header to your request.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I was wondering if that factored in. I'm new to this aspect of mobile dev, I'll check this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like your problem:

```golang
var user models.User
if user.ID == 0 {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "error": "Invalid email and/or password",
    })
    return
}
```

Assuming the `ID` on a `models.User` is just an `int`, the default *is always zero*! You probably want to load the user, e.g. from the DB, before checking the `ID`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and I will definitely fix it. The API does test fine in Postman already and the error is only occurring when I test in Android Studio, so I'm thinking it must be a Flutter/Dio problem. I could be wrong though. I'll check it out

Comment: @NicholasGoldstein Are you sure you're hitting the same API / endpoint in both Postman and Flutter/Dio? That block doesn't look like it'd work *ever*.

Comment: You were right. It wasn't working in Postman either. I tested it awhile ago and assumed it was working. I must've changed that and forgot about it. I'm still getting the Dio error as well, but I'll keep digging. Thanks

Comment: @NicholasGoldstein Writing automated tests as you go is really helpful - they likely would have caught this for you :)